# Entlib validation ErrorMessage not working with MVC ValidationMessageFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, enterprise-library

I'm using the combination described on the title. If I use DataAnnotations the ErrorMessage I set is shown correctly on MVC 2 form validations. However if I switch the validation to Entlib 5, with the same ErrorMessage property set, the error message shown is a deafult one, depending on the validator, and not the one I set.

Before, working:

[Required(ErrorMessage="The field name is required.")]
public virtual string Name { get; set; }

After:

[NotNullValidator(ErrorMessage="The field name is required.")]
public virtual string Name { get; set; }

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually setting the wrong property for this one.

Instead of

```
[NotNullValidator(ErrorMessage="The field name is required.")]
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
```

it should be

```
[NotNullValidator(MessageTemplate="The field name is required.")]
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
```